# Strange FANN behavior in spam classification task

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, spam-prevention

I tried to write simple spam classifier with help of FANN library. To do it I collected number of spam and ham email letters, and collected a dictionary of the most used English words.
I created a neural network with one hidden layer with the following code:

```
num_input = get_input_size(dictionary_size)
num_output = 1

ann.create_standard_array((num_input, num_neurons_hidden, num_output))
ann.set_activation_function_hidden(libfann.SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC)
ann.set_activation_function_output(libfann.SIGMOID_SYMMETRIC)
ann.set_training_algorithm(libfann.TRAIN_INCREMENTAL)
```

Output is 1 when the letter is ham and -1 when it is spam. Each of the input neurons represent if a specific word was in an e-mail or not (1 - word was in a mail. 0 - was not)

To train neural network I use the following code.
(For each e-mail letter in a training set)

```
# Create input from train e-mail letter
input = get_input(train_res, train_file, dictionary)               
ann.train(input, (train_res,))
```

To check if an e-mail from a test set is a spam or not I use the following code:
(For each e-mail in a test set)

```
input = get_input(SPAM, test_spam, dictionary)
res = ann.run(input)[0]
```

But no matter what size of dictionary I use (I tried from 1000 words to 40000 words) or number of neurons in the hidden layer (20 to 640) after my network is trained it assumes that almost all e-mails are spam or ham. For example I receive either results like this:

```
Dictionary size: 10000
Hidden layer size: 80
Correctly classified hams: 596
Incorrectly classified hams: 3845
Correctly classified spams: 436
Incorrectly classified spams: 62
```

where almost all spams are classified correctly, but all hams are misclassified, or results like this:

```
Dictionary size: 20000
Hidden layer size: 20
Correctly classified hams: 4124
Incorrectly classified hams: 397
Correctly classified spams: 116
Incorrectly classified spams: 385
```

that are oposite.
I tried to use more training data. I started with approximately 1000 e-mails in training set (the proportion of spam to ham is almost 50:50) and now I am testing it with approximately 4000 e-mails (spam:ham approximately 50:50), but result is the same.

What is the possible problem?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you asserted that there is a **significant** difference between spam and ham mails in terms of their content of the words in your wordlist? My guess would be that there might not be a very clear difference between spam and ham when it comes to the content of regular words.

If you are using 'real' spam mails many spamers use something known as **Bayesian poisoning** where they include lots of 'legitimate' text in order to confuse spam filters. Since you simply filter on content of usual word and not on words statistically common to spam/ham your approach will be very sensitive to bayesian poisoning.

Comment: Are you doing this because you are trying to learn about ANN:s or because you need a good spam filter? If you need a spam filter i think you should abandon the ANN approach.   

A good place to start can be   
[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_spam_filtering)
  
If you are simply trying to learn neural networks i think it would be better to try pattern recognition in images or something like that were neural networks actually perform well.   
  
If you are set on filtering spam with ANN I would try to extract some features of the mails, common words, letter counts, etc.

Comment: I think you are right. The reason why I could not train my network was Bayesian poisoning. I tried different training strategies, but it didn't help.

Comment: My primary reason to do this was to learn how ANNs work. But negative result is still a result right? :) Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about FANN, but for spam classification the training regimen is important. First of all: **don't train all ham mails and then all spam mails**. Mix them together, preferably pick a mail at random, then train it, whether it is ham or spam.

Other than that, there are quite a few different ways of deciding whether the classifier should be trained on a particular message at all. For example, if the classifier already thinks a message is spam, and then you train it as spam, it may develop an unwarranted prejudice against the words in that message.

Possible training regimens include (but are not limited to):

- TEFT (Train Everything)

  Train everything once. Usually not a good choice.
- TOE (Train on Error)

  Train only on mails the classifier gets wrong.
- TTR (Thick Threshold Training)

  Train all mails the classifier gets wrong, or that lie on a "thick threshold". For example, if everything below 0.0 is spam, train on all emails classified as between -0.05 and 0.05.
- TUNE (Train Until No Error)

  Do TOE or TTR repeatedly, until the classifier correctly classifies all training mails. This can help, but it can also hurt, depending on your training data.

There are variations on each of these, but Thick Threshold Training will usually give good results: Because it does not train *every* mail, it is less prejudiced against words that appear in spam, but that don't really help with the ham/spam decision (for example the Bayesian poisoning Niclas mentioned). And because it trains on borderline cases, even though it classified them correctly in the training run, it gets more experience with such borderline cases and is less likely to be fooled by them in actual use.

As a last remark: I am assuming you're using Neural Networks to learn more about them, but if you actually need to filter spam, [Naive Bayes](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) or the [Winnow algorithm](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Winnow_%28algorithm%29) are usually more appropriate.